# Highlight Specific Dates in jQuery Using DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I would like to highlight a date & add message to that date when I drag the mouse on it. the code is:-

```
<head runat="server">
<title>HoliDayHighlight</title>
<link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language= "jscript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('07/10/2013')] = new Date('07/10/2013');
    SelectedDates[new Date('07/15/2013')] = new Date('07/15/2013');
    SelectedDates[new Date('07/20/2013')] = new Date('07/20/2013');

    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
            if (Highlight) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
});​

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="height: 220px">
<div style="height: 191px; width: 1156px">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

I want it should display a message on the date. Ex:- We declared that 15th july is a holiday.When I hover the mouse on the 15th in the calender,a small message will display(ex:-today is holiday)when I remove the mouse the message will dis appear.

I think this code is wright. But, when i click on the text Box the calender is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following code i just tested it's working :)

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <title> Datepicker Swappy</title>
   <script type='text/javascript'        src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css"
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <style type='text/css'>
    body
    {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size : 10pt;
    padding:5px;
    }

  .Highlighted a
  {
    background-color : Orange !important;
    background-image :none !important;
    color: White !important;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }

  </style>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(window).load(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('04/05/2014')] = new Date('04/05/2014');
    SelectedDates[new Date('05/04/2014')] = new Date('05/04/2014');
    SelectedDates[new Date('06/06/2014')] = new Date('06/06/2014');

   var SeletedText = {};
    SeletedText[new Date('04/05/2014')] = 'Holiday 1';
    SeletedText[new Date('05/04/2014')] = 'Holiday 2';
    SeletedText[new Date('06/06/2014')] = 'Holiday 3';    

   $('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
        var HighlighText = SeletedText[date]; 
        if (Highlight) {
            return [true, "Highlighted", HighlighText];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
       }
     });
    });
  });
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type='text' id='txtDate' />
 </body>
</html>
```

Happy coding :)